# How did the plane get through the dome?

Tags: under-the-dome

Can someone explain how the plane in the opening sequence falls inside the dome when we saw it hit the outside and explode?

The dome can stop a nuke but not a light aircraft? Am I missing something?

Comment: -1 Because this is honestly a little silly.

Answer (score 10):

because it was under the dome at the time of 'the event' and hit the **inside** wall.

This is confirmed in the [original novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Dome) by Stephen King:

> These thoughts went through Barbie’s mind in seconds; the shadow of
>   the airplane was still between him and the chuck, a black cross racing
>   along the highway. Then two things happened almost simultaneously.
>
> The first was the woodchuck. It was whole, then it was in two pieces.
>   Both were twitching and bleeding. Barbie stopped, mouth hanging open
>   on the suddenly lax hinge of his lower jaw. It was as if an invisible
>   guillotine blade had dropped. And that was when, directly above the
>   severed woodchuck, the little airplane exploded.
>
> Barbie looked up. Falling from the sky was a squashed Bizarro World
>   version of the pretty little airplane **that had passed over him seconds
>   before.** Twisting orange-red petals of fire hung above it in the air, a
>   flower that was still opening, an American Disaster rose. Smoke
>   billowed from the plummeting plane.
>
> Something clanged to the road and sprayed up clods of asphalt before
>   spinning drunkenly into the high grass to the left. A propeller.

Answer (score -1):

It hit the inside. The plane was *inside* of the town.